# How can I check from Android WebView if a page is a "404 page not found"?

Tags: android, webview

I want to check a "404 page not found" from a WebView and if it's a 404 then I revert to the previous page.

### Edit

Also the webpages I want to see are pure .jpg 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg but I have no info of how many images exist. So if anyone can propose another method, they are welcome to do so.

Comment: You may want to check out [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1d2f0b04b2818181/) from the android-developers group.

Answer (score 24):

Starting SDK 23 (Android M) you can use `onReceivedHttpError` method to catch 404 and other HTTP errors. Just override inside your `WebViewClient`

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpError (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "HTTP error "+errorResponse.getStatusCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `This callback will be called for any resource (iframe, image, etc), not just for the main page` - from the docs

Comment: I tried this but my code just skips over it when I get a 404 on an API 24 device.

Comment: Do you know if this can be used to detect failed AJAX requests? Or is it only for resources fetched from the main document?

Answer (score 16):

I might be a few years too late, but here is how I had to solve it since none of these answers worked.

I ended up using onReceivedTitle and comparing the title with the title of the page (in this case "page not found") from the site I was trying to open.

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);


            CharSequence pnotfound = "The page cannot be found";
            if (title.contains(pnotfound)) {
                pagenotfound = true;
                view.stopLoading();
                webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stackoverflow");

            }
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
    });
```

The "pnotfound" will be different from site to site. But usually one site use the same "page not found" therefore you can use the Title on the site.
You might want to add a else if for if you're using multiple sites.

Hope it helps for someone.

Comment: Thank you for providing this hack. It seems that there is not a straight-forward (non-hacky) way to figure out a 404.

Comment: This is a great answer!! This definitely worked for me and saved me hours of banging my head against the wall!!! Thank you for sharing!!!

Comment: While clever, this is not a good solution. You may be tempted to just check for Android's stock "Webpage not available" to detect a network error but be aware that this will break for any other language (and not to mention the OS could change this title in the future).

Answer (score 4):

I would try to detect loading of 404 page. You can do that by implementing `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method in the `WebViewClient` class.

```
mGenericWebClient = new GenericWebClient();
mWebView.setWebViewClient(mGenericWebClient);

public class GenericWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (url=="your404page.html") {
            view.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
   }
}
```

You can also check if `onReceivedError` event appears, when 404 error occurs.

Comment: what if 404 page NOT controlled by me? Visiting some anonymous site returns 404?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to fully load the page to check if it results in a 404 error:

```
private int getRange() {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        int Count = 1;
        URL testURL;
        while (true) {
            testURL = new URL(
                    (myURL + "/" + Integer.toString(Count++) + ".jpg"));
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) testURL
                    .openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            if (con.getResponseCode() == 404) {
                return Count - 2;
            }
            Log.e("RESPONCE", Integer.toString(con.getResponseCode()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a WebView, which was the original question.

Comment: I beg to differ with the down-votes of this answer. Three years after this answer was posted the Android `WebView` still doesn't offer any means of checking the HTTP status of the currently loaded page. This leaves the developer with external solutions, such as @weakwire's contribution. It must be understood that the suggested solution is to be used as a "pre-validation" step, before (and if) delegating the URL loading to the `WebView`. I choose to leave the code quality uncommented, though.

Comment: It seems this is still the case in April 2017, eh? @dbm

Answer (score 1):

I might be very late for this thread but here's how I solved it. As, my application deals with dynamic URLs and multilingual websites, none of the above solution worked for me. And `onReceivedHttpError` can get called for any resource (iframe, image, etc), not just for the main page so I decided to add a check for the mainPage.

So here's how I did it:

```
 @Override
public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
    if (request !=null && request.getUrl() !=null)
        if (request.getUrl().toString().equals(dynamicURL) && errorResponse.getStatusCode()==404) {
            //Handle the error
        }
}
```

Here, `dynamicURL` is main url which gets loaded in the activity's `webview`. By adding this check I now only get error if the main page throws 404.

PS: This might won't work for you if your page's url does not return 404.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   super.onPageFinished(view, url);
   String pageTitle = myWebView.getTitle();
   String[] separated = pageTitle.split("-");
   if(separated[0].equals("404")) {
       Log.i(TAG, "detect page not found error 404");
   }
   else {
       findViewById(R.id.progress1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are webmaster of the page which is loading in webview you can set your page title like '404'. Then after your page is loaded you can get page's title with the `getTitle()` method. Then if it contains `404` or if it is different from your page title you can do what you want.

Example:

```
myView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {  
           String pageTitle = myView.getTitle();
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), pageTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Comment: The title returned may or may not 404 in it. Different platforms and/or devices may return a different title name.

Comment: I have edited my answer, as if user is webmaster of the page.