# Is it possible to configure a error page ( Activity ) for entire android application.?

Tags: android-manifest

I am new to android application. In web application, we can configure error page for the entire application in web.xml.

Like that, is it possible to configure a error page ( Activity ) for entire android application.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about web apps (app with a db conection not talking about WebView) I told you to consider the use of toast/notifications/Alerts before using an entire Activity:

See [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-alert/) web

Taling about webpage (using the WebView i tell you to use this code extracted from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181843/how-can-i-check-from-android-webview-if-a-page-is-a-404-page-not-found):

```java
private int getRange() {
try {
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
    int Count = 1;
    URL testURL;
    while (true) {
        testURL = new URL(
                (myURL + "/" + Integer.toString(Count++) + ".jpg"));
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) testURL
                .openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        if (con.getResponseCode() == 404) {
            return Count - 2;
        }
        Log.e("RESPONCE", Integer.toString(con.getResponseCode()));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}enter code here
return 1;
}
```