# disable error Web Page Not Found "

Tags: java, android

I want to create a web app for android.
When I click a button the app opens a web page.

If I have internet connection the app is working fine.

If I disable internet connection I get a message : "Web Page not found", and is shown with link of web page.

My question is :

**1 :** How to protect link of web page and

**2 :** How to disable error message of **Web Page Not Found**

Comment: Check for internet connection prior to the display and if not found load a html with your own error msg instead of loading the original link..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181843/how-can-i-check-from-android-webview-if-a-page-is-a-404-page-not-found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think an example can help you.

- you can use `WebViewClient` to get the error events.
- In this event `load` an error `HTML` page

the code sample is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class TestWebView extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_image_layout);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullScreenImageWebView);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * 
             * @see
             * android.webkit.WebViewClient#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView
             * , int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
             */
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                loadError();
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    private void loadError() {
        String html = "<html><body><table width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<td><div align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\" size=\"20pt\">Your device don't have active internet connection</font></div></td>"
                + "</tr>" + "</table><html><body>";
        System.out.println("html " + html);

        String base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(html.getBytes(),
                android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        webView.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
        System.out.println("loaded html");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**first you have to check internet connection using below code snippet**

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
// if no network is available networkInfo will be null
// otherwise check if we are connected
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Then check the value of Boolean variable if it returns true then your connection available and if it returns false then display some error messages to user.

**I hope you will got my logic**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if webview permits this, but you can [check the internet connection](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/android-detecting-internet-connection/) first. If connection is available then display the WebView, if not show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
try {
webView.stopLoading();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
try {
webView.clearView();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
if (webView.canGoBack()) {
webView.goBack();
}
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/path_to_file");
super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}a

private WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
  // ... override whatever, including the onReceivedError method above
}
WebView webView = new WebView(context);
webView.setWebViewClient(client);
```

you can check up with above code