# Loading a different site if one fails

Tags: android, android-webview

I am making an app that requires me to load up a website inside a webview. However sometimes the website fails to load up. It's a server side problem so can't do anything about it. However I was thinking if there is any way that I can check if the sever is down and automatically redirect to another website. Any help would he greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This should do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181843/how-can-i-check-from-android-webview-if-a-page-is-a-404-page-not-found

Comment: I assume you would want to adapt this approach to deal with a timeout or server 500 error, because it sounds like the failure wouldn't be a 404 (file not found)

Comment: Yes I have to deal with server 500 error. The servers stops responding at a certain time time of the day. I am using 000webhost to host a website

Comment: You could also try something like CloudFlare. CloudFlare serves a "this site is offline" page if it detects a 500 or timeout from your existing server. You just point your DNS at CloudFlare and then point CloudFlare at your web host. It also does other cool things (full disclaimer I am a satisfied customer)

Comment: Hi thanx for the suggestion....I'll definitely try it out