# Android: How to check for successful load of url when using webview.loadUrl

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In webview android I am trying to load a url and in order to check if the load of this url is done successfully (internet connection was available, the server was up etc) I was under the impression that webview.loadUrl  would throw exceptions, but wrong! as it explicitly is stated in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) "an exception will NOT be thrown".

So how can I check to see if webview.loadUrl did not fail ?

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: @manishkumar Sure, please give me time to test it

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately, currently there is no easy way in WebView to ensure that everything on the page has been loaded successfully. We are hoping for a better API to come up in future version. Let me explain what you can do now.

First of all, in order to detect any problems that prevent WebView from making a connection to the server for loading your main page (e.g. bad domain name, I/O error, etc.), you should use `WebViewClient.onReceivedError` callback as other people correctly suggest:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        // Make a note about the failed load.
    }
}
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

If the server connection was successful, and the main page was retrieved and parsed, you will receive `WebView.onPageFinished` callback, so you also need to have this in your `WebViewClient` subclass:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Make a note that the page has finished loading.
    }
    ...
}
```

The caveat here is that if you have received an HTTP error from the server (e.g. a 404 or a 500 error), this callback will be called anyway, it's just the content that you will get in your WebView will be a server error page. People suggest different ways of how to deal with it, see the answers here: [How can I check from Android WebView if a page is a "404 page not found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181843/how-can-i-check-from-android-webview-if-a-page-is-a-404-page-not-found) Basically, it really depends on what you expect to be a "good" page and a "error" page. Unfortunately, there is currently no way for the app to get the HTTP response code from WebView.

The callbacks `WebViewClient.onPageStarted` and `WebViewClient.onProgressChanged` are only useful if you want to draw a progress bar as you are loading the page.

Also note that the way of overriding `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` that people usually suggest is not correct:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)         {  
        // !!! DO NOT DO THIS UNCONDITIONALLY !!!
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

What few developers realize is that the callback is also called for subframes with non-https schemes. If you'll encounter something like `<iframe src='tel:1234'>`, you will end up executing `view.loadUrl('tel:1234')` and your app will show an error page, since WebView doesn't know how to load a `tel:` URL.
It is recommended to simply return false from the method, if you want WebView to do the loading:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)         {
        // Returning 'false' unconditionally is fine.
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

This doesn’t mean you should not call `WebView.loadUrl` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` at all. The specific pattern to avoid is doing so unconditionally for all URLs.

Comment: In `onRecievedError()` you can check if the failing url equals the original url you loaded into the WebView  and find out if the main document has not loaded.

Comment: Sure! The same holds for `onPageFinished` and other callbacks.

Comment: onReceivedError is not being called. Target API level is < 23, so I can't use the non-deprecated version.

Comment: @Michael There is no issue in using the old version of the API if your app expects to run on older versions.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class AppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            setProgressBar(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //Page load finished
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            setProgressBar(false);
        }
}
```

and then you can do

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClient());
```

For the error part you can override the `onReceivedError` method

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}
```

Comment: What do I need to import for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with, it works like a charm.

```java
    Boolean failedLoading = false;
    WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("www.example.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (!failedLoading) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webView.setAlpha(0f);
                ObjectAnimator anim  = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(webView, "alpha",1f);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            failedLoading = true;
        }
    });
```

It will also work great if you add some kind of a refresh button and then you can call the code above inside a function to try again.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if a URL is loaded successfully by using `onProgressChanged()`

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    //your url is loaded successfully 
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: **This does not work** , progress will reach 100 even if it fails to load. The answer by @Mikhail Naganov is probably the best one.

Comment: @JonasCz, Agree, But as per my knowledge, when webview loads a url and if the webpage fails to load, it comes directly to 100, so we can modify the code, like if(progress==99), what do you say?

Comment: Progress might not be exactly 99, since it could jump from 80 straight to 100. (Look at progressbar in aosp browser.)

Comment: Wrong, Practically, if a url fails to load, progress go 10 to  100