# Forwarding to other www if url returns error. How to write this?

Tags: java, android, url, android-webview

I need an android WebView app which forwards to "second" url if first url returns error: **(ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)**.

Below I pasted java code. It works fine for one url but I need sth like an if statement.
I tried to do this by `onReceivedError` method but I can't do this.

I'm new in Android development so I need your help ;)

Java code:

```
package com.example.webview;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you can explore this question first, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385768/android-how-to-check-for-successful-load-of-url-when-using-webview-loadurl

Comment: Thanks but it's not very helpful for me :/